# GStreamer plugin to post progress to REST service

Tags: plugins, gpu, load-balancing, gstreamer

For load balancing my GPU based GStreamer tasks I would like to send the percentage of work done on the GPU side to a remote task scheduler service.

I am not that deep into GStreamer, so my question is:
can this be done with already available plugins (e.g. `progressreport ! tcpserversink`), or do I have to create a special *progressreport* plugin, that outputs its messages to an http service?

Comment: Sounds like an application task to me rather than a plugin. I would build an app and on the pipeline's bus I would act on the `progressreport` reports and make the REST call.

Comment: Yes, load balancing definitely is a task for an application, but not necessarilly a GST application. The progressreport plugin would just provide the needed input to decide which GST task would be the best candidate for the next job..